# Apache Tika extracting metadata via jar but not in sample code

Tags: java, apache-tika

I've been able to extract metadata via the tika-app executable jar using the following line:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.13.jar --metadata example_received_regular.msg
```

It prints out all of the metadata.  But when I try to execute a simple extraction of the same file in a Java program, I don't get any of it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser");
    FileInputStream des = new FileInputStream("/Users/jason/docstore/example_received_regular.msg");
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    String detected = tika.detect(des);
    Metadata tikaMetadata = new Metadata();
    parser.parse(des, handler, tikaMetadata, new ParseContext());
    String[] names = tikaMetadata.names();
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + tikaMetadata.get(name));
    }
    System.out.println(detected);
}
```

My first thought was that the tika-parser library was somehow unavailable at runtime, hence me attempting to load the TesseractOCRParser on the first line, but that class loads just fine.  Executing this program results in the following output:

```
X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
application/x-tika-msoffice
```

This seems like the most basic example of Tika metadata extraction I can find anywhere.  The extraction runs fine with the jar but not in this example.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TikaCLI` program utilizes a special `TikaInputStream` object which populates the metadata (unlike the `FileInputStream` in your example above).

You can make the following changes in order print the metadata values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("/Users/jason/docstore/example_received_regular.msg");
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    Metadata tikaMetadata = new Metadata();
    InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(file, tikaMetadata);
    parser.parse(input, handler, tikaMetadata, new ParseContext());
    String[] names = tikaMetadata.names();
    Arrays.sort(names);
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + tikaMetadata.get(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, using the TikaInputStream worked.  The get(File file, Metadata metadata) method in your example was actually deprecated though, so I ended up using the get(Path path, Metadata metadata) version.

Comment: TikaInputStream only adds file length to the metadata object (if a file/path is sent to it), no other metadata.  I think what was happening was that the file stream wasn't correctly reset before the parse.  TikaInputStream typically does the right thing with mark/reset, and we recommend it always.